# How to exclude logo from collapsed navbar? [Bootstrap/HTML]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make it so when a user is on their desktop, the logo of the website will be visible in the middle of the navigation bar. However, I also want to make it so when the user is on mobile, the logo changes position to be on the top right of the screen, and the button to activate the navbar to be on the left. Currently, I have it in the center and it just stays there which results in it also being in the collapsed navbar. How can I make it so it's excluded from there?

```html
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        <img src="logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="45">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's really difficult to answer see without your full code, at least you have to share your header section code & screenshot!

Comment: @NazmulHossainPappu I don't have a header section - this block of code is the only thing I have inside my body section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the way I would approach this:

Add `d-none d-lg-block` classes to the middle logo `img` tag so it displays only desktop.

Then add a duplicate `img` as the last item in your `.container-fluid` and add `d-block d-lg-none` classes to it so it will display on mobile but not desktop.

Then add `flex-nowrap` to your `nav` tag, so the logo will appear inline with the toggle button.

Lastly, add `align-self-start` class to the duplicate/mobile `img` so it will stay inline with the toggle button when the nav is open.

It should look something like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark flex-nowrap">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <img class="d-none d-lg-block" src="https://mk0leanfrontierqpi7o.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-placeholder-png.png" alt="" width="100" height="45">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="d-block d-lg-none align-self-start" src="https://mk0leanfrontierqpi7o.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-placeholder-png.png" alt="" width="100" height="45">
</nav>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/poRXmMK)

Is this what you're looking for?

**[UPDATE]**

I didn't see that you were using Bootstrap 5. I added a `.text-end` container that wraps the `button.nav-togger` and the `.navbar-collapse` and added a few other utility classes for style.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark flex-nowrap flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar justify-content-end justify-content-lg-center">
   <div class="text-end">
      <button class="navbar-toggler mb-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav container-fluid justify-content-center p-0">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <img class="d-none d-lg-block" src="https://mk0leanfrontierqpi7o.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-placeholder-png.png" alt="" width="100" height="45">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        
      </div>  
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <img class="d-block d-lg-none align-self-start" src="https://mk0leanfrontierqpi7o.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-placeholder-png.png" alt="" width="100" height="45">
</nav>
```

With Bootstrap 5: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/vYgoGoL)

Comment: Hey, this is pretty much what I wanted, except I wanted the image and navbar toggler buttons to be swapped. Also, for some reason, when I enable the toggle, the positioning of the elements messes up.

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/1b7ffdde70acc1f2d0034097764fab6a

Comment: I edited the codepen to swap the positioning. I added `.flex-row-reverse` to the `nav`, `.justify-content-end` to the `.container-fluid` that wraps the `.navbar-toggler` and the `.navbar-collapse` and a `.text-right` to the `.navbar-nav`. Do you have any questions on what I did there and why?

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting issues with the positions of the navbar elements when you click on the toggle. See the screenshot below

https://gyazo.com/7c27adac018ca3ea181b05f32f373256

Comment: Could you post your code? Then I can help more.

Comment: Hi there. So sorry I didn't see that you were using bootstrap 5. I made a new codepen (https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/vYgoGoL) and edited some classes to get this to work. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Alright, so it positions itself properly now. However, for some reason, the height of the navbar increases and I don't like it higher. Is there any way I can decrease the height so it was like before?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that doesn't require duplicating the logo. To exclude the logo (or any other content) from the collapse navbar it has to be removed from the `navbar-collapse` div...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-lg-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
            <a class="mx-auto" href="#"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/50/ccff00" class="rounded-circle"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto text-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/BL17fggy1m